# How to extract the data using FILTER function in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to extract the rows where `Action 1` & `Action 2` appear in the same Group. Which means, if the particular group only have either `Action 1` or `Action 2`, then it will no extract the data. In the screenshot above, only Group A and Group C have both `Action 1` and `Action 2`, so the formula will extract it out.

I'm able to use Query function in google sheet to do this but I'm not sure what can I use in excel. I'm trying to use `FILTER` function. Hope to get some advice on this any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It can be other method if FILTER function is not suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MMULT to find the correct Group and Match to bring only the correct action.

```
=FILTER(A3:B12,(MMULT(COUNTIFS(A:A,A3:A12,B:B,{"Action 1","Action 2"}),{1;1})=2)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3:B12,{"Action 1","Action 2"},0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried to apply the formula to all the rows below by changing the formula to `=FILTER(A3:B500,(MMULT(COUNTIFS(A:A,A3:A500,B:B,{"Action 1","Action 2"}),{1;1})=2)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3:B500,{"Action 1","Action 2"},0))))`, however, it seems like making my excel sheet a bit lagging, is this normal?

Comment: This is an array formula, it will do a lot of calculations.  So that many rows, it would be a bit slower.

Comment: Sorry, just a quick question for understanding, what does it means by putting `{1;1}` in 2nd array of `MMULT`?

Comment: That is a vertical array.  It needs to have the same number of items in the other arrays.  So if you were looking for three items you would need to add another 1: `{1,1,1}` it is how MMULT works.  It multiplies a 2D array by a vertical 1D array and sums by row.